# converting Excel-date string to date and time

Tags: r, excel, date, datetime

I have imported some data from Excel containing a date and time cell. When I try to convert the data into a date and time format I only get very strange results. If I go for only date there is no problem and I get the correct date. (I am working in MacOS)

```
date <- 40259.93645833333

as.POSIXlt(date,origin='1904-01-01 00:00:00')
"1904-01-01 12:10:59 CET"
as.POSIXlt(date,origin='1970-01-01 00:00:00')
"1970-01-01 12:10:59 CET"
as.POSIXlt(date,origin='2010-01-01 00:00:00')
2010-01-01 12:10:59 CET"
as.Date(date,origin='1904-01-01')
"2014-03-23" #Correct date
```

I would like to know how to proceed and keep the time as well.

Comment: What is the origin in your excel? What is the first year?

Comment: The date specified is the first date in my Excel file.

Comment: Did you tried XLConnect? It should import data correctly (also with dates).

Comment: I imported my data using xlsx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number passed to `as.POSIXlt` are seconds since the origin:

```
as.POSIXlt(date*24*3600,origin='1904-01-01 00:00:00')
[1] "2014-03-23 23:28:29 CET"
```

Also, generic advice recommends using `POSIXct` instead of `POSIXlt`.